# How to debug function declared on Spyder IPython console

Tags: debugging, ipython, spyder

how do I debug and step into a function that I declared interactively on Spyder Ipython?

As an example, I have the following function that I declare interactively:

```
def my_function(x,y):
    w = x*2
    z = y*2
    return w+z
```

I did some reading online, it looks like to debug I have to load the py script first. As an example:

```
$ python -m pdb hello.py
```

Can I debug without loading the script?

I want to call my_function(1,2) and see what values are the w and z.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following line inside your function

```
def my_function(x,y):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    w = x*2
    z = y*2
    return w+z
```

Then after you call it in the console like this

```
my_function(1, 2)
```

you'll be taken to the debugger automatically.